# Неправильное отображение даты и времени в Plotly

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, plotly

Редактирую чужой код.
Input: Множество xlsx-файлов с несколькими полями, одно из которых временное в формате ДД-ММ-ГГГГ чч:мм:сс. Иногда после секунд бывают непонятные остатки.

[image: Пример временной метки в xlsx данных]

Имеющийся код на основе библиотеки Plotly состоит из множества самописных и вложенных друг в друга функций, он читает xlsx-файл, и создает отчет с несколькими интерактивными графиками множества параметров от времени в HTML-формате.

Кода много, поэтому вопрос абстрактный: почему половина однородных с виду xlsx-файлов обрабатывается корректно:

[image: Корректная временная метка]

, а половина со странными числами, похожими на те, которые получаются, если в Excel дату и время обратить в десятичный формат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал вручную определять форматы временного поля, и как Общий, и как Текст, и Время и Дата, но не помогает.

Подскажите идею?

Comment: покажите по 1 строке с данными к обоим вариантам на скринах

Comment: Можете выложить __воспроизводимый__ Excel файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: Файл с данными, на которых строится проблемный html по ссылке

https://yadi.sk/i/1M7xw0kyrr36Tg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После некоторых проб и ошибок пришел к такому варианту:

```
import datetime as dt

def get_excel_date(col):
    res = pd.to_datetime(col, errors='coerce')
    mask = res.isna()
    res.loc[mask] = pd.to_timedelta(col[mask].astype('float'), unit='d') + dt.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
    return res

 df = pd.read_excel(r"D:\download\Sample.xlsx")
 df['Date'] = get_excel_date(df['Время'])
```

---

```
In [53]: df[['Время','Date']]
Out[53]:
                            Время                          Date
0      2018-10-31 23:44:59.996000 2018-10-31 23:44:59.996000000
1             2018-11-01 00:00:00 2018-11-01 00:00:00.000000000
2      2018-11-01 00:04:34.999000 2018-11-01 00:04:34.999000000
3             2018-11-01 00:15:00 2018-11-01 00:15:00.000000000
4      2018-11-01 00:25:19.999000 2018-11-01 00:25:19.999000000
5      2018-11-01 00:29:59.996000 2018-11-01 00:29:59.996000000
6      2018-11-01 00:44:54.996000 2018-11-01 00:44:54.996000000
...                           ...                           ...
20909           43511.65497684028 2019-02-15 15:43:09.998976000
20910                 43511.65625 2019-02-15 15:45:00.000000000
20911          43511.657638888886 2019-02-15 15:47:00.000009600
20912          43511.666666666664 2019-02-15 16:00:00.000028800
20913           43511.67708328704 2019-02-15 16:14:59.995996800
20914           43511.67988425926 2019-02-15 16:19:01.999977600
20915                  43511.6875 2019-02-15 16:30:00.000000000

[20916 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Как всегда, спасли! Кстати, следующий вопрос будет по Plotly. Знакомы с этой либой?

Comment: @StepanSokol, немного знаком...

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что в некоторых Excel файлах время сохранено с миллисекундами. Возможно, некая ошибка округления, так как 999 миллисекунд выглядят очень подозрительно.

Прямо в Excel можно нормализовать данные таким образом:

```
= ROUND(A1*24*60*60,0)/(24*60*60)
```

Или

```
= ОКРУГЛ(A1*24*60*60,0)/(24*60*60)
```

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если значение записано в виде текста, как в примере файла, добавленном автором вопроса, то его предварительно нужно преобразовать в числовой формат:

```
= DATEVALUE(A1)+TIMEVALUE(A1)
= ДАТАЗНАЧ(A1)+ВРЕМЗНАЧ(A1)
```

Comment: `=ОКРУГЛ(A2*24*60*60;0)/(24*60*60)`

Эта формула дает некорректный вывод #ЗНАЧ!

Comment: @StepanSokol Посмотрите [здесь](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%97%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%A7-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-15e1b616-fbf2-4147-9c0b-0a11a20e409e), как решать такую проблему. Попробуйте для начала ввести ручками пример, который я привел на скриншоте, чтобы убедиться, что формула работает. А потом выясните, почему она не работает с Вашими данными. Я подозреваю, они сохранены как текст, а не как datetime

Comment: @StepanSokol Скачал файл с данными. Там действительно текст, как я и подозревал. Преобразуйте текст в числовой формат. Я добавил формулы в ответ